# What is Max and Min size of Applet in java card

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I am working on java card and i want to know:

1. what is max and min size of an applet in java card and on which parameter it depends?
2. How many applet we can install on smart card?

I am using:

- smart card type = contact card
- using java card 2.2.2 with jcop using apdu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official size limit (above the ones Robert already posted). Cards may have their own limits depending on available memory - but there is no fixed value for that; depends on what has already been installed, how their VM works internally and so on.

Comment: if smart card size is 32kb then max size of applet is 32kb is that true?

Comment: Almost certainly - but usually a less because of VM, OS, library overhead. Note that some cards may even align data differently as well, so your applet may take up more or less bytes as well. Ask NXP!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a concrete limit for the applet size, however there are other limits that affect the maximum size:

According to the Java Card 2.2 Virtual Machine Specification the limits are as follows:

**Package References:**
A package can reference at most 128 other packages.

**Package Name:**
The fully qualified name of a package may contain a maximum of 255 characters.
The package name size is further limited if it contains one or more characters which,
when represented in UTF-8 format, requires multiple bytes.

**Classes in a Package:** 
A package can contain at most 255 classes and interfaces.

**Interfaces:**
A class can implement at most 15 interfaces, including interfaces implemented by
superclasses. An interface can inherit from at most 14 superinterfaces.

**Static Fields:**
A class in an applet package can have at most 256 public or protected static non-final
fields. A class in a library package can have at most 255 public or protected static
non-final fields. There is no limit on the number of static final fields (constants)
declared in a class.

**Static Methods:**
A class in an applet package can have at most 256 public or protected static methods.
A class in a library package can have at most 255 public or protected static methods.

**Methods:**
A class can implement a maximum of 128 public or protected instance methods, and a maximum of 128 instance methods with package visibility. These limits include inherited methods.

**Class Instances:**
Class instances can contain a maximum of 255 fields, where an int data type is counted as occupying two fields.

**Arrays:**
Arrays can hold a maximum of 32767 fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specification that mentions the maximum size for an applet. It all depends on OS, so yeah you should definitely ask NXP.