# Global Platform Load returns 6A84 - Card Limitation?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I have a JCOP Java Card 2.2.2 J2E145 by NXP.

There's already a large applet present on the card, approximately **90 kB** of on card size.

I am trying to upload another CAP file on the same card, but with no success. `INSTALL FOR LOAD` (`INS = E6`) works, but the subsequent `LOAD` (`INS = E8`) command fails with `6A84 (Not enough memory space in the file)`.

I would like to make my CAP file smaller in order to make it uploadable, but I am really not sure where to cut first.

As far as I know, both `INSTALL FOR LOAD` command and the very first `LOAD` command contain no information about the total size that is going to be uploaded by subsequent commands. That is why I suppose the absolute size of the package is probably not the issue, because I can upload another (although a little smaller) CAP file successfully and I don't think there is not enough space on the card even for the very first block of data.

Is there any other limitation which could result in `6A84` status word for the very first `LOAD` command because of some information in the beginning/header of the CAP file?

Guessing: Total count of static methods? Total count of packages? Total count of static fields?

[What is Max and Min size of Applet in java card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628300/what-is-max-and-min-size-of-applet-in-java-card) is related, but it is not a duplicate of my question; it covers limitations for one class only, but I would like to know limitations for the whole card.

Comment: Just to add another guess: Since a Javacard stores all its variables in non-volatile memory, the "dynamic" variables have to be considered the same way as the mentioned static ones. It seems  plausible, that these are allocated during LOAD.

Comment: Try and make sure you don't load any debug.cap (inside the main cap). Note that there *are* limitations to the different components, with the 64KiB limit of the methods.cap being the main one. As you haven't got to the INSTALL for INSTALL I doubt the RAM is an issue.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes This is a limitation for methods.cap of a single package, right? Not for all methods.caps over all packages on the card. I checked it and the large applet already present on the card has 84kB of methods for its 11 packages. The smaller applet I try to upload is much smaller. Can I run out of space for methods on the card before I run out of total space?

Comment: @vojta With regards to the total amount of methods: I cannot *remember* any minimum or limitation in that regards within the Java Card standard. But yes, limitations may still be imposed by the OS implementation. I do however *assume* most cards implement a single / simple heap for the EEPROM where the type of data doesn't matter. There may however be other requirements for the methods; possibly maybe (please don't ask because I won't be able to answer - even if I did remember).

Comment: Give us the APDU commands, maybe we can find out the reason.